# Validating a user story in rally

Tags: rally

We have a requirement to enforce the user to put the User Story ID in every SVN commit comment. There will be a precommit hook which will check whether the comment starts with User Story number(just a regex pattern matching). Once that validation is over, we have to validate whether this user story actually exists in rally.

I tried to get some useful idea from rally restful API guide, but could not succeed. Feebly I was able to recognize that it has got something to do with HierarchialRequirement, but that knowledge wont suffice.

Please let me know how I can say a user story number(of the format US12345) is valid or not for the given workspace.

@nickm there is an issue with story information being retrieved using the restful service.
If I give the correct user story ID e.g US12345, it works as expected by fetching the information.
But when I give invalid userID like US123451111111, it throws parse error("Could not parse US123451111111"). This is not true for all the invalid story IDs that are provided to the restful service. If I give US12345cccccc(a valid storyID followed by aplhabets), I still get the response for the correct User story US12345.

Please advise how to work around this.

Thanks,
Venu

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a Ruby script based on [Rally REST toolkit for Ruby](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby) that you may customize so that the precommit hook calls it to see if the story actually exists in the workspace

As it is written, it requires a command line parameter to run,e.g.

ruby find_story.rb US123

```
require 'rally_api'

headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()
headers.name = "find story"
headers.vendor = "Nick M RallyLab"
headers.version = "1.0"

config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:api_key] = "_abc123"
config[:workspace] = "W1"
config[:project] = "Sample Project"
config[:version] = "v2.0"
config[:headers] = headers #from RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()

unless ARGV.length == 1
  puts "enter one argument, e.g. US123, with no spaces"
  exit
end

story = nil
story_id = ARGV[0]
puts "find story by FormattedID: #{story_id}"

@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :story
query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID,ScheduleState"
query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/111" } 
query.query_string = "(FormattedID = \"#{story_id}\")"  
result = @rally.find(query)

if(result.length > 0)
    puts "found the story"
    story = result.first
    puts "FormattedID: #{story["FormattedID"]}, Name: #{story["Name"]}, ScheduleState: #{story["ScheduleState"]}"
else
   puts "did not find a story with FormattedID #{story_id}" 
end
```

The toolkit provides a syntactic sugar but underneath there is `hierarchicalrequirement` endpoint that queries by FormattedID

```
(FormattedID = US123)
```

where 1111 should be replaced with the Object ID of your workspace in `/workspace/1111`:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111&query=(FormattedID%20%3D%20US123)&start=1&pagesize=20
```

You may test this URL directly in the browser. If you are not currently logged in to Rally in another tab of the same browser you will be prompted to login.

Comment: Could you please advise how to workaround this problem?

Comment: In WS API a query (FormattedID = US2918xyz) will return 0 results and will not return an error. You may extend the code above by adding validations aginst all possible invalid formats using regexp http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html

Comment: Hi, It returns the results for US2918xyz and US2918..there is no difference in the JSON result in both the cases..thats the reason I am surprised..may be a bug?

Comment: To work around you may use regexp to disallow it. For example, I tested this regexp editor http://rubular.com/ to validate "US123" format and disallow "US123x": ^US[0-9]+$ You may further specify that lower case "us" is also acceptable, etc